# Cannot click a button by its known Element Id on Webbrowser #Vb.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net, webbrowser-control

My application is some kind on Mini Web Browser application. In my application I have button for sign in to Google which will do the work for Google's **'Sign In'** or more specifically **'Next'** button. I can get the **ElementId** by using **Inspect Elements** and the **ElementId** for the button is ***"passwordNext"***. But when I try to click the button using my button it fails as if the program cannot find any element with this **Id**.

> **Screenshot (*ElementId* for 'Next' Button):**

[image: SS1]

> **Code:**

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        If Not IsNothing(wbMain.Document.GetElementById("passwordNext")) Then
            wbMain.Document.GetElementById("passwordNext").InvokeMember("Click")
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember the `WebBrowser` control uses an old IE version (not the latest one you have installed necessarily), and I noticed you are using Chrome to debug (which I also was at first). If you look at the source code the webbrowser generates, you will notice the button has a different ID of `id="next"`. So just change your code to look like this:

```
If Not IsNothing(wbMain.Document.GetElementById("next")) Then
    wbMain.Document.GetElementById("next").InvokeMember("Click")
End If
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: Nice work. But your code will work only on the first attempt when he write an email and click but on the next button 'passwordNext' it won't work.